# React apps are not deploying on heroku, how to deploy without using eco dynos

Tags: javascript, reactjs, heroku

React Apps are no longer working on Heroku, something related to free eoc dynos changed from 28th of november 2022, this is the exact message

[image]

Is there a way to deploy react app on Heroku without using paid dynos ?

Comment: No. The free tier doesn't exist any more. If you didn't upgrade the plans for those apps by the deadline they were deleted.

Comment: This was communicated well ahead of time through multiple channels. Note that your apps may not have been _deleted_, though. They are probably just deactivated to give you an opportunity to upgrade.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Heroku closed the free tier https://blog.heroku.com/next-chapter on November 28, 2022

**You can no longer host your apps for free**